# Safari Browser Does Not Render Div Used as Vertical Line

Tags: html, css

I have some very simple HTML/CSS for creating a vertical line:

```css
.verticalLine {
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.root {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="verticalLine"></div>
 <div>
```

While this works in Chrome it doesn't render at all in Safari. If you place content into the div it will render the line but only the height of the text you place inside the div. Any ideas how to make a vertical line in a Safari Browser?

Answer (score 0):

try adding **display: inline-block;** to your **verticalLine** class|

I would also add **margin-left: 1px;** to correct for the border width =)